# Dynamic create Material Dialog with the content is any Component in Angular 6

Tags: angular, dynamic, angular-material, dialog

I just wonder if it's possible to create a directive that can generate these things:

- The button the triggers show the dialog (1)
- The dialog with the content generated by passing some block of code inside the content area of the directive (2)

In detail, it will be something like this in the template file:

```
<div popup>
      <div #button><button>Open Popup</button></div> <!-- (1) -->
      <div #content> <!-- (2)  -->
        <user-creation (submitted)="onCreate($event)" [roles$]="roles$"></user-creation>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a **Widget** which is reusable and it's constructed using one or more angular components.
As the first step open the terminal of the project's directory and create those two widgets.

1. Create your button component `ng g c buttonComponent --module app`
2. Create your button component `ng g c contentComponent --module app`

After that go to button-component.component.ts and content-component.component.ts files and look for the **@Component** decorator and get the **selector** value. In your case, it should be app-button-component and app-content-component .

So now you can use those values in any view in you angular project. simply use **< app-button-component >** and **< app-content-component >**  you can specify what should happen when you click the button inside the component.ts file in your  **app-button-component**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Got your point! However, I still got another issue. Hope you to join this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52490243/close-button-of-matdialog-in-angular-get-error-cannot-read-property-close-of-n  . Thanks!