# Close button of MatDiaLog in Angular get error Cannot read property 'close' of null

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog

I want to create a component with multiple content project in angular 6. It might be

This is the content I passed from the `app.component.html`:

```
<popup>
  <button buttonTrigger mat-button><span >Open the popup!</span></button>
  <my-dialog-content content></my-dialog-content>
</popup>
```

This is the content of the `popup.component.html`

```
<div (click)="openDialog()"><ng-content select="[buttonTrigger]" ></ng-content></div>
<ng-template #dialogContent>
  <ng-content select="[content]"></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

And this is the content of the dialog content:

```
<mat-dialog-content>
my-dialog-content works!
</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <ng-container ngProjectAs="btn-close"><button mat-button color="warn" matDialogClose>Close</button></ng-container>
    <button mat-button color="primary" type="submit" cdkFocusInitial>Submit</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

This seems work except for the close button:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of null

This is the link to my source code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-ngcontent

I don't know if there will be solution or good idea to fix this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dialog.closeAll()`, below is the changes you have to do in your code

here's an example

in `my-dialog-content.component.html`

```
<mat-dialog-content>
    my-dialog-content works!
</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <ng-container ngProjectAs="btn-close">
    <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="dialog.closeAll()">Close</button>
  </ng-container>
    <button mat-button color="primary" type="submit" cdkFocusInitial>Submit</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

and in `my-dialog-content.component.ts`

```
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material';

export class MyDialogContentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

}
```

Updated [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-ngcontent-n5hpa4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-dialog-content%2Fmy-dialog-content.component.ts)

Comment: HI, @vuquanghoang

Comment: I still have a question: is it possible to bubble up the event of my-dialog-content.component.html into app.component.html by using @Output?

Comment: Yes you can use Output... see this https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-ngcontent-ahendp?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Wow. I thought it's impossible because the middle component would be popup. It turns out that I'm wrong. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of issue and it turned out to be an issue on the service maybe because you're sending some kind of callback it thinks that the error come from there